# Pandas dataframe moving from as_matrix to to_numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker

Here is my code:

```
def predict(data, rows=500):
    split_array = np.array_split(data, int(data.shape[0] / float(rows) + 1))
    predictions = ''
    for array in split_array:
        predictions = ','.join([predictions, xgb_predictor.predict(array).decode('utf-8')])

    return np.fromstring(predictions[1:], sep=',')

data_test["predictions"]= predict(data_test.as_matrix()[:, 1:])
```

xgb_predictor is a Sagemaker model object.

This no longer works since as_matrix() is not supported.

How do I replace this with to_numpy()?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `data_test` is a pandas matrix, then you should be able to directly use `to_numpy()` instead.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html:

```
Deprecated since version 0.23.0: Use DataFrame.values() instead.
```

`DataFrame.values()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values

```
We recommend using DataFrame.to_numpy() instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, here is the new code using to_numpy()

```
 def predict(data, rows=500):
        split_array = np.array_split(data, int(data.shape[0] / float(rows) + 1))
        predictions = ''
        for array in split_array:
            predictions = ','.join([predictions, xgb_predictor.predict(array).decode('utf-8')])
    
        return np.fromstring(predictions[1:], sep=',')
    #replace data_test["predictions"]= predict(data_test.as_matrix()[:, 1:]) with
    data_results["predictions"] =  predict(data_test.iloc[:,1:].to_numpy())
```